# Ruby : unexpected ',', expecting '.' or &. or :: or '['

Tags: ruby, function, unexpected-token

I'm currently trying to implement a mathematic method to approximate
f(x) = 0. I've already implemented it in some languages and I want to do it in ruby now just for training.
But I have this error that I really does'nt understand
Here is my code

```
def fonction (x)
    return (x ** 3) + 4 * (x ** 2) - 10
end

def derive (x)
    return 3 * (x ** 2) + 8 * x
end

def newton(f, fPrime, n, u0)
    if n == 0 then
        return u0
    else
        uN = newton (f, fPrime, (n - 1), u0)
        return uN - f(uN) / fPrime(uN)
    end
end

for i in 0..6
    puts (newton (fonction, derive, i, 2))
end
```

Comment: The spaces between the method name and its parentheses are causing the problem. However, since parentheses are optional in Ruby when calling a method, writing `fonction` will already _call_ that method. To pass the method as an object, you'd use `method(:fonction)` and call it via `f.call(uN)`. It might be easier to use actual functions here, i.e. a [Proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Proc.html) or lambda instead of a method.

Comment: Yup, my code is working right now thank you

Comment: When you report an exception in a question please give the type of exception and its location, as well as the error message. Here it is a syntax error that was raised when the last comma in `...N = newton (f, fPrime, (n - 1), u0)` was parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there is space on newton method call

```ruby
uN = newton (f, fPrime, (n - 1), u0) # there is space after newton
```

also in this one

```ruby
for i in 0..6
    puts (newton (fonction, derive, i, 2)) # there is space after newton
end
```

try remove it, and you will see another error i guess, i try it on repl

Comment: Yes it was quite an obvious porblem, it solved many things.

Comment: @TanguyMacé please mark the answer as accepted in order to give appropriate credit.

Comment: mark please @TanguyMacé